# Apply multiple filters using checkboxes and list.js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, filter, listjs

I am trying to filter some results based on a group of check box's, using list.js plugin.

I have managed to sort by one criteria at the moment, which only sorts by one item at a time i.e. only easy, only moderate, but when I try and select multiple checkbox's at the moment it doesn't work ie. selecting both easy and moderate at the same time.

Does anyone have any advice how I can do this. The html and javascript are below.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="search-results">
    Sort by: 
    <button class="sort btn" data-sort="name">
        Name <i class="fa fa-fw"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="sort btn" data-sort="date">
       Departures <i class="fa fa-fw"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="sort btn" data-sort="difficulty">
       Difficulty <i class="fa fa-fw"></i>
    </button>

    Filter:
    <label for="easy">Easy</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="easy" class="filter" data-value="Easy" />
    <label for="moderate">Moderate</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="moderate" class="filter" data-value="Moderate" />
    <label for="challenging">Challenging</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="challenging" class="filter" data-value="Challenging" />


    <div class="list">

        @foreach (var page in umbracoPages.OrderBy(x => x.Difficulty))
        {
            <div class="package">
                <span class="name">@page.Name</span><br />
                <span class="date"><strong>@page.Date @(page.Date == 1 ? "departure" : "departures") available</strong></span><br />
                <span class="difficulty">@page.Difficulty</span>
            </div>
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dateFrom, #dateTo").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
        constrainInput: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: 0
    });

    var options = {
        valueNames: ['name', 'date', 'difficulty' ]
    };

    var userList = new List('search-results', options);


    //filter
    $('.filter').change(function() {
        var bool = this.checked;
        var value = $(this).data("value");

        userList.filter(function (item) {
            if (item.values().difficulty == value && bool == true) {
                return true;
            } else if (userList.filtered && bool == false) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }


        });

        return false;

     }); });
```

Comment: A working example of the code above can be found here: http://codepen.io/JasonEspin/pen/zGvjwR

Answer (score 9):

You need to store active filters in an array and check against all of them.

```
$(function() {
var options = {
    valueNames: ['name', 'date', 'difficulty' ]
};

var userList = new List('search-results', options);
var activeFilters = [];

//sort
userList.on("updated", function () {
    $('.sort').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("asc")) {
            $(this).find(".fa").addClass("fa-sort-asc").removeClass("fa-sort-desc").show();
        } else if ($(this).hasClass("desc")) {
            $(this).find(".fa").addClass("fa-sort-desc").removeClass("fa-sort-asc").show();
        } else {
            $(this).find(".fa").hide();
        }
    })
})

//filter
$('.filter').change(function() {
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    var value = $(this).data("value");

    if(isChecked){
        //  add to list of active filters
        activeFilters.push(value);
    }
    else
    {
        // remove from active filters
        activeFilters.splice(activeFilters.indexOf(value), 1);
    }

    userList.filter(function (item) {
        if(activeFilters.length > 0)
        {
            return(activeFilters.indexOf(item.values().difficulty)) > -1;
        }
        return true;
    });
 });

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbOYaG